# I am trying to install git on my mac and it's showing the same error while installing any package

Tags: macos, terminal, apple-silicon

Code in terminal:

```
harshdhariwal@Harshs-MacBook-Air ~ % $ brew install git
zsh: command not found: $
harshdhariwal@Harshs-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Please remove `$` sign at the beginning of the command. Just `brew install git`.

Comment: I did but now it's showing zsh: command not found: brew

Comment: Then you need to install brew first.

Comment: issue got resolved thanks for the help

Comment: I've added an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `$` from your command line. It's a command prompt and probably was copied from a tutorial you were using.

Also before you install anything with `brew` you need to install `brew` itself. See [here](https://brew.sh/) on how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not include the '$' in your command. only run 'brew install git'

Answer (score 0):

First, Install homebrew by running:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

If you get:

```
fatal: cannot force update the branch 'master' checked out at '/opt/homebrew'
```

Run the commands:

```bash
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"'
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

Finally try running `brew install git`